# Посчитать самый популярный ответ для каждого вопроса

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Есть список, состоящий из списков, в кот 2 элемента, вопрос и ответ.
Мне нужно посчитать самый популярный ответ для каждого вопроса.
Попробовал воспользоваться Counter из collections, пока не получилось.
Пример списка.

```
lst = [['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'да'], ['Как и во что был одет курьер?', 'нет'], ['Курьер соблюдает субординацию?', 'да'], ['Курьер проявляет индивидуальный подход?', 'нет']]

cnt = collections.Counter()
for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        cnt[j] += 1
```

Так он выведет просто самое популярное, независимо от элементов.
метод most.common() дает список из пар самых часто встречающихся элементов.
А я не понимаю как эту логику объединить или получить структуру какую-то.
Мне нужно, чтобы код выдавал самый популярный ответ(в виде ответа, а не числа) для кажд вопроса

Comment: Добавьте пример списка и вашу попытку с `Counter`, т.к. `Counter` правильное направление решения

Comment: Добавил, пока не дошло(

Comment: Обычно в `Counter` засовывают список, а он по нему возвращает словарь, где ключом будет элемент, а значением -- количество в том списке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или вот так:

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'да'],
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'нет'],
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'не помню'],
    ['Как и во что был одет курьер?', 'нет'],
    ['Курьер соблюдает субординацию?', 'да'],
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'нет'],
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'не помню'],
    ['Курьер проявляет индивидуальный подход?', 'нет'],
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'не помню'],
]
df=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['Вопрос','Ответ'])

df.groupby(['Вопрос']).apply(lambda x: x['Ответ'].mode())
```

Ответ:

```
Как и во что был одет курьер?                 нет
Курьер поздоровался с вами?              не помню
Курьер проявляет индивидуальный подход?       нет
Курьер соблюдает субординацию?                 да
```

Comment: будем значит изучать панду, спасибо, красиво

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter


lst = [
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'да'],
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'нет'],
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'не помню'],
    ['Как и во что был одет курьер?', 'нет'],
    ['Курьер соблюдает субординацию?', 'да'],
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'нет'],
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'не помню'],
    ['Курьер проявляет индивидуальный подход?', 'нет'],
    ['Курьер поздоровался с вами?', 'не помню'],
]

question_by_answers = defaultdict(list)
for q, a in lst:
    question_by_answers[q].append(a)

for question, answers in question_by_answers.items():
    top_answer = Counter(answers).most_common(1)[0][0]
    print(f'{question!r} - {top_answer!r}')
```

Результат:

```
'Курьер поздоровался с вами?' - 'не помню'
'Как и во что был одет курьер?' - 'нет'
'Курьер соблюдает субординацию?' - 'да'
'Курьер проявляет индивидуальный подход?' - 'нет'
```

Comment: спасибо, понятное решение

Comment: @НикитаСмяцкий, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)